# What is the meaning of "Except I am your dad"?

Tags: meaning

Nathan ran away from Dave & Gus because he got embarrassed by her Dad actions, Later Gus found Nathan & tells him that he is doing to get money. But Nathan didn't bother & take a walk then Gus say this words to him:

> Oh, well, I may as well not bother. **Except I'm your dad**.

Comment: Again you have not cited your source. (a film "The Full Monty"). You have not explained a difficulty. The meaning of "Except, I'm your dad" is entirely literal. You must identify a particular concern.

Comment: In this context, ***except = but***. Which you could understand as short for ***But** [contrary to the implications of what I just said] I'm your dad [and therefore I **must** bother]*. I'd say this ***except** [statement]* (as opposed to ***except** [noun]*) usage is relatively informal, as is the "reverse" phenomenon recently gaining traction whereby we often encounter ***Because** [noun]* (where historically the standard construction was always ***Because** [statement]*).

Comment: It means that if he were someone else, he would not have bothered.

Answer (score 1):

> Oh, well, I may as well not bother. Except I'm your dad.

is the same as saying

> Oh, well, I may as well not bother. Except *that I will bother, and the reason why I will bother is because* I'm your dad.